# How to retrieve query string from url of content loaded into a dojo tab container?

Tags: layout, dojo

I have a dojo TabContainer where the tabs are created based off what is selected in a tree. The content of the tabs is loaded in the following manner:

```
var cp = new dojox.layout.ContentPane({ 
    title: name + " Report",
    closable: true,
});

cp.set("href", "SomePage.html#" + name);
cp.placeAt(dijit.byId("contentTabs"));

dijit.byId("contentTabs").selectChild(cp);
```

SomePage has an associated JS file that runs the content for that page. How can I extract the hash tag from the URL? The location object gives me back the top level URL for the dojo app.

Answer (score 0):

In the JS of SomePage you can get access to the contentpane widget and get its href attr

```
cp.attr('href');
```